# Text data in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am really confused with this Text data in Haskell. Can someone explain me what values it has, where can it be used and what actually is the difference between it and a normal String. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

A `String` is a list of `Char`s, it is defined as:

```
type String = [Char]
```

This is however not a good format when you want to process a large amount of text in bulk. The overhead in terms of memory, and in cycles will be quite large.

The `Text` data type stores characters as a chunk of UTF-16 characters. This thus means that there is no memory overhead, and furthermore it is better in terms of caching if the characters are located next to each other, so processing is done faster.

If you make use of strict `Text` (the one you import from `Data.Text`), then it means that the text needs to fit in memory. The `Data.Text.Lazy` works with chucks, and thus lazily calculates the next chunk, and thus can sometimes operate on strings that do not fit in memory in total.

Answer (score 2):

- **Text** Contiguous memory that contains UTF-16 encoded text.
- **String** A linked list of individual characters (inefficient, but having a list makes quick-and-dirty parsers easy to write)
- **Lazy Text** from `Data.Text.Lazy` is a linked list of chunks of `Text` allowing streaming of text in constant memory.

Comment: Specifically, `Text` uses 16 bits per character, whereas `String` uses 24 *bytes* per character!

Comment: It's not just the space but the indirections which are not friendly to branch prediction or cache lines.